# Efeito para duas divs se moverem para lados opostos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso que duas `divs` Tenham o efeito de transição, igual a [desse site](http://carlespalacio.com/) (apertem as setas do teclado "UP" e "Down" para ver oque estou falando).

Preciso que quando o usuário rolar o *scroll* para baixo, as `divs` e seus conteúdos respectivos mudem conforme o exemplo que citei. Ou seja, quando for *scrollado* para baixo, a `DIV` da esquerda sobe e a da direita desce. Essa alternância pode ser randômica.

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
}
.right{
  float:right;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
}
#tela1 .left{
    background:#000;
}
#tela1 .right{
    background:#888;
}
#tela2 .left{
    background:#689;
}
#tela2 .right{
    background:#366;
}
```

```html
       <div id="tela1">
           <div class="left">
               Conteúdo da esquerda que move para baixo
           </div>
           <div class="right">
               Conteúdo da direita que move para cima
           </div>
        </div>
      <div id="tela2">
           <div class="left">
               Conteúdo da esquerda que move para baixo
           </div>
           <div class="right">
               Conteúdo da direita que move para cima
           </div>
        </div>
```

Postei a [minha estrutura aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/juulhao/z417erpq/4/):

Comment: Quer fazer isso com teclado também? Proponho que coloque no seu fidde uma imagem para podermos dar exemplo. Entretanto dê uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/j1vhzpf2/

Comment: segue a idéia do @Sergio e usa um keyup/keydown http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keydown.asp

Comment: Você pode usar um Framework, por exemplo, o Skrollr, ou outro Parallax scrolling for the masses. 
http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ Existem algumas boas opções, pesquise por "JavaScript Scroll Framework".